# I was asked to write a "sentence" with operators (operator precedence)

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I'm completely new in programming and Python, and my teacher gave me the instructions to write an equation:

c = month ≡ day ∨ day ¬ onth

where ≡ is the identity, ∨ the "or" and ¬ the (logical) negation. I don't really know how to do this, because when I try typing

```
c=month is day or (day not month)
```

Python tells me, that I made a syntax error and I don't know how to fix it. I'm not sure about operator precedence too. I hope you understand my problem as I find it quite hard to tell what's going on because English isn't my first language.

Comment: [is](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_is.asp), [or](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_or.asp), [not](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_not.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question is "Translate that logical equation into an actual Python expression".

That equation is a bit weird because ¬ as the negation is a *unary* operator, i.e. it turns true to false and false to true. So having it show up *between* two variables is strange.

Your syntax error in Python is related to that: The `not` can't just occur between two variables. What *would* work, from the syntax, is something like

```py
c = month is day or (day is not month)
```

but that's a bit of a weird formula because if you think about it, that's just *always* true: Either `month` is `day`, in which case the first part of your `or` is `True`. Or `month` is not `day`, in which case the second part of the `or` is `True`.

Comment: thank you so much sor answering! you saved my day! :D